# In Jmeter is there a listener that will just report the Transaction Controller Responses?

Tags: jmeter, report, listener

When I run tests and look at the aggregate report, I'm getting the Transaction Controllers as well as the actual calls within the controller.

Is there a way to get a listener/report that will just use the transaction controller response time?

Answer (score 0):

summary report will provide transaction controller response times 
Note : you have to select generate parent sample in translation controller

Answer (score 0):

Make sure "Generate parent sample" is checked under "Transaction Controller" element.
[image]

You should see the expected result
[image]